# как получить pixel color в формате Bitmap.Config.RGB_565

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь получить данные пикселя из Bitmap.Config.RGB_565. Вместо ожидаемых 2 байт цвета
через int pixelColor = bitmap1.getPixel(x, y); получаю 4 байта color = ff8c785f. Точно так же как
из  Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;Подскажите, нужно какую то маску одеть? Ниже код:

```
public void showMyPicture(byte[] data){

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig =  Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                //Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length , options);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, WidthMyPicture, HeightMyPicture, matrix, true);
```

И функция показывающая color:

```
public String showPixelColor(int x, int y) {
        int pixelColor = bitmap1.getPixel(x, y);
        
        String info = String.format("x= %d ; y=%d \n", x, y);
        info += String.format("color = %x  ;", pixelColor) +
            Integer.toBinaryString(pixelColor) +  "\n";
        //bitmap1.setPixel(x, y, 0xffff0000);
        return info;
    }
```

Comment: Этот метод всегда выдаёт `ARGB_8888`. Если вам нужен только один пиксель - проще его преобразовать самому. Код для этого легко найти в сетях. Все пиксели разом и в исходном формате можно получить в `Buffer` методом `copyPixelsToBuffer()`

Comment: А скажите зачем вам это? Просто система все преобразования делает за вас при получении и установке точек.

Comment: Спасибо woesss! Это ответ на мой вопрос. copyPixelsToBuffer() решает мою проблему).

Comment: To Style-7: конечная цель сравнение изображения, байты нужны чтоб сделать хэш. Готового решения не нашел, только направления). Вот изобретаю велосипед(. Если подскажете где есть пример программного кода, буду очень признателен)